# Ajax, Struts and a Null Pointer

Tags: ajax, struts, nullpointerexception

I've recently developed a simple ajax search. The whole code in my server is using Struts, so I had to use a somewhat cumbersome way of programming. My main method returns an ActionForward. I programmed in a way that I would send the text to the client, and then return a null action forward.

This works perfectly.

...except, it generates a Null Pointer error in the log. And our production log usually sends an email every time an error occur. How can I get rid of this error? Is there any other way (that doesn't involve another framework)?

Thanks!

Comment: *What* generates an NPE? Returning a `null` just means the action itself handled writing the response and Struts doesn't need to do any more processing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say your "Main method" are you refering to your Action Class? If this is called via ajax, you can set your return type to void.

Comment: Yes, but I used the same class to do a get and a post. The get method returns the action-forward (to the right JSP), and the post will execute the ajax command. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Maybe I'm still misunderstanding how you have it setup but can't you leave the get method as is with the ActionForward return type and then change the post method to return void?

Comment: I'm extending a class that the project uses, and the main method returns an action forward. Here:
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletCommonRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, CaduniiRuntimeException,
   CoreIspRuntimeException, RuntimeException, CoreIspException,
   CaduniiException, UsuarioNaoEncontradoNaSessaoException,
   SessaoInvalidaException, FuncionarioNaoLogadoException,
   UsuarioInconsistenteException, JSONException, IOException {

Comment: I think you'll have to just create another method in your Action Class that mirrors the execute method in your parent class but returns void. Perhaps there's another way but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the NPE might exist in your application, not in struts. I found myself facing the same issue today, and was really puzzled. Struts supports returning a null ActionForward, so there is no reason to get an NPE.

So I dug into the NPE and found that it was being thrown by a class belonging to our application. This class inherits the struts DispatchAction class, and is in turn inherited by all the action classes in our application.

To make a long story short, although struts supported a null ActionForward, the descendent class did not. Once I tweaked the descendent class to handle null values, the NPE went away.